# .NET Deserializing JSON to multiple types

Tags: .net, json, deserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserializing JSON into one of several C# subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429546/deserializing-json-into-one-of-several-c-sharp-subclasses)

I have read-only access following JSON schema:

```
{ items: [{ type: "cat", catName: "tom" }, { type: "dog", dogName: "fluffy" }] }
```

I would like to deserialize each of these to their respective type:

```
class Cat : Animal {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
class Dog : Animal {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My only thought at this point is to deserialize them to a `dynamic` object, or `Dictionary<string, object>` and then construct these objects from there.

I may be missing something from one of the JSON frameworks out there....

What would your approach be? =]

Comment: The accepted answer here is arguably much better than the answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think it's likely you'll need to deserialize the Json then construct the objects from there. Deserializing directly to `Cat` or `Dog` won't be possible as the deserializer won't know how to construct these objects specifically.

**Edit**: borrowing heavily from [Deserializing heterogenous JSON array into covariant List<> using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net)

Something like this would work:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string Type { get; set; }
}

class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string CatName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string DogName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

class AnimalJson
{
    public IEnumerable<IAnimal> Items { get; set; }
}

class Animal
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class AnimalItemConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter<IAnimal>
{
    public override IAnimal Create(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IAnimal Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        var type = (string)jObject.Property("type");

        switch (type)
        {
            case "cat":
                return new Cat();
            case "dog":
                return new Dog();
        }

        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("The animal type {0} is not supported!", type));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Load JObject from stream 
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Create target object based on JObject 
        var target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        // Populate the object properties 
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }
}

string json = "{ items: [{ type: \"cat\", catName: \"tom\" }, { type: \"dog\", dogName: \"fluffy\" }] }";
object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnimalJson>(json, new AnimalItemConverter());
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I like the example, but unfortunately all the properties are not shared. I have updated my example to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I marked my question as a duplicate, but I think this is a better answer.

Comment: Well answered. Thank you for the edit.